# No tAda after requesting from faucet

Tags: testnet, documentation, cardano-faucet

I'm following the [docs](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/stake-pool-course/handbook/keys-addresses) and ran:

```
cardano-cli query utxo \
    --address $(cat payment.addr) \
    --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

and it shows my address but no tAda several minutes after requesting from [this](https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/tools/faucet/) faucet. My testnet is synced and I'm doing this from Debian 11. It wasn't fully synced yet; that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the faucet and received the 1,000 tADA after about 4 minutes.

You can check the testnet explorer for your initial attempt to see what it says: https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/en

What is your test address, I'll send you the 1,000 tADA.

**Edit** (for others that end up on this page)

Ensure you are fully synced, check with:

> cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1097911063

Comment: addr_test1qzfdl3vkyjemg28jfnewsd4qldhemrnrl5np268dswzeaehavclrvqjk72kgfpfs567zpp2r9klu6hkhwynrgjdyr0lq2fpzgv

Comment: Explorer shows two transactions but still no balance locally. Not sure if I'm supposed to install the wallet or if just running the node and cli is enough.

Comment: Ok it sounds like a local sync issue. Can you run `cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1097911063` to see if you're local storage is fully synced.

Comment: Also, check your node log file for any issues/errors.

Comment: `{
    "era": "Alonzo",
    "syncProgress": "91.73",
    "hash": "40f26cdcfff0319d11f3eacb0fb7230fcbf5694afc85499188178229cf87264e",
    "epoch": 178,
    "slot": 46727389,
    "block": 3202975
}`

Guess I'm not fully synced yet though the stdout messages don't have any 'progress bars' or anything.

Comment: It's progressing but very slowly so I think something's off.

Comment: Ok, only 91% synced (syncProgress). Also use https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/en.html to see the latest SLOT and BLOCK values, and compare to your values. Once synced you'll see your trxs and balance.

Answer (score 0):

```
cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

showed that it wasn't fully-synced yet.

Comment: I am tempted to delete this answer as it is more a hint than an explanation.  The guidelines in [answer] will help improve your answers.